# What datums are required for an Oauth 1.0 replay attack?

Tags: authentication

I am working with some software where the vendor creates log files on exception.  The files include a number of Oauth fields, and the vendor claims this is not a security risk.  The Oauth fields include:

- consumer key
- nonce
- signature method
- timestamp
- token
- body hash
- signature
- realm

Does this leave the software vulnerable to a replay attack?  Or any other kind of attack?